# "How truer" vs. "How much truer"

Tags: comparatives, subcontinental-english

Which sentence is grammatical? If both sentences are grammatical, which sounds more idiomatic?

> How much truer and kinder an act of giving is when one gives away what you need.

or

> How truer and kinder an act of giving is when one gives away what you need.

Comment: There's a few oddities: It's odd to mix "one" and "you" at the end there. Yes, they're both impersonal pronouns (at times), but you can't mix them. Second, "is when" is not very idiomatic. You would be better off saying "is giving away..." I added this as a comment because it doesn't address the *much* part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is correct.

> How much truer and kinder an act of giving is when one gives away what you need.

To paraphrase, "giving is kind and true, but it is much truer and kinder when giving away something you need."

I'm not sure what the construct is called, but it's turning the question "how much kinder is it to do X instead of Y?" into a statement, "how much kinder it is to do X." This is a more emphatic way to say "It is kinder to do X instead of Y."

"How kind it is to do X" is also valid. The *much* is only required when using the comparative form, *kinder*, to note that X is *kinder than* Y.

A [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=how%20kinder%2Chow%20much%20kinder&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chow%20kinder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chow%20much%20kinder%3B%2Cc0) supports this option.